# Can I change the root of the treeview generated by Doxygen?

Tags: treeview, doxygen

Can I change the root of the treeview with a custom link instead of index.html?
Or at least add html before the treeview on the side-nav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is not with the vanilla Doxygen.

However, you may be able to get someway by using the '@page' documentation, which Doxygen will include before the API tree.

Doxygen also recognises '.dox' files as *just* containing Doxygen comment blocks - while not required for @page, these are useful where the supporting documentation is not linked to any particular source file.  I've used these in the past to build the full SDK document, with background, examples, etc.

A variant is the '@mainpage', which comes first - otherwise @page entries are unordered.  In the past I have modified Doxygen to order @pages by their internal name (as opposed to their title).